# Working with SQLite database in assets without copying it on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Copying .sqlite file takes too much time. Can I work with it in assets folder?

Comment: You *cannot* change any resources in your app.

Comment: I don't need to change this DB.

Answer (score 0):

> Copying .sqlite file takes too much time. Can I work with it in assets
>   folder?

If you will place **.db** file there, for sure it will works but this is not the best choice but it depends on more things. Efficient way is to place file on SD card and only provide reading from it. This is useful if your db file has bigger size.

But also all possible approaches have advantages and disadvantages. For example placing database on sd card is not really safe but effective if db file has big size. Do you imagine case if you have db file that have for example 200 MB. Placing it into assets folder is "sick".

Also it depends also on character of application, supposed size of db, desired performance etc.

Here is basic snippet of code of you want to read from:

```
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            return db;
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: 20 MB. Do I need to copy it on SD Card? User is needed to wait for ten seconds because of copying.

Comment: @Vladiator you shouldn't have this big file in assets because .apk file will be automatic have very big size...instead of this i recommend you to place .db file somewhere on Internet(on drobbox for example) and when user first start application you will check if db exists on sd, if not, perform downloading.

Comment: @Vladiator you will show some infomation dialog? ... and this will happen only once..

Comment: I show the dialog, but I didn't see apps that loads so long (even in the first time) with not very big databases (20 MB).

Comment: @Vladiator i think that downloading 20mb file will take max. 1-3 minurtes, depends on speed.